# MVC 4 Details page being parsed 2 id's

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

can anyone think why I am not getting the desired output for when i click on the details link? 
I get the error : `The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[AW_Internet.Models.ProdList]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'AW_Internet.Models.ProdList'.`

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id1 = 0, int id2 = 0)
{
    string test = "SELECT SalesLT.Product.ProductID, SalesLT.ProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID, SalesLT.Product.Name, SalesLT.Product.ListPrice, LEFT(SalesLT.ProductDescription.Description, 20) as Descrption FROM SalesLT.Product, SalesLT.ProductDescription, SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription WHERE SalesLT.Product.ProductModelID = SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription.ProductModelID AND SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID = SalesLT.ProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID AND SalesLT.Product.ProductID = " + id1 + " AND SalesLT.ProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID = " + id2;
    var viewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdList>(test).ToList();
    if (viewModel == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(viewModel);          
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ProdList
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public int ProductDescriptionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal ListPrice { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Details View:

```
@model AW_Internet.Models.ProdList

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Prod Details</h2>

<div class="displayField">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductID)
</div>
<div class="displayField">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductDescriptionID)
</div>
<div class="displayField">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="displayField">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ListPrice)
</div>
<div class="displayField">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
</div>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

And the snippet from my Index with the two id's being parsed:

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id1 = item.ProductID, id2 item.ProductDescriptionID })
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you expect multiple `ProdList` items returned from your query then update your view to:

```
@model List<AW_Internet.Models.ProdList>
```

and update how you're referencing everything in your view. It's more likely you're trying to return a single record so you should write:

```
ProdList prodList = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdList>(test).FirstOrDefault();
```

---

and you probably want to update your method as well, since it will never be equal to `null` where you're checking, and if it were, it would have thrown an exception when you `.ToList()`'ed it.

```
public ActionResult Details(int id1 = 0, int id2 = 0)
{
    string test = "...";

    var viewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdList>(test).ToList();

    if (!viewModel.Any())
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(viewModel);          
}
```

or the more likely scenario where you only want 1 record:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id1 = 0, int id2 = 0)
{
    string test = "...";

    ProdList prodList = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdList>(test).FirstOrDefault();

    if (prodList == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return View(prodList);          
}
```

---

Maybe try to update your variable names as well - :)

Answer (score 3):

On your Details method, you returned a `List<ProdList>`, and in your view, you declare a `ProdList`. You have to return a single element like this :

```
public ActionResult Details(int id1 = 0, int id2 = 0)
{
    string test = "SELECT SalesLT.Product.ProductID, SalesLT.ProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID, SalesLT.Product.Name, SalesLT.Product.ListPrice, LEFT(SalesLT.ProductDescription.Description, 20) as Descrption FROM SalesLT.Product, SalesLT.ProductDescription, SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription WHERE SalesLT.Product.ProductModelID = SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription.ProductModelID AND SalesLT.ProductModelProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID = SalesLT.ProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID AND SalesLT.Product.ProductID = " + id1 + " AND SalesLT.ProductDescription.ProductDescriptionID = " + id2;

    var viewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdList>(test).ToList();
    if (viewModel == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(viewModel.First());          
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That solved it thanks! Would it be the same sort of method for douing an Action Result Edit? Just changing around the query offcourse to an Update

Comment: You have to return on the same model as declared on your view. On your example, you returned a `List<ProdList>` and you view use a `ProdList`

Answer (score 2):

`db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdList>(test)` returns a collection and your page expects a single element. You could do:

```
var viewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<ProdList>(test).FirstOrDefault();
if (viewModel == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(viewModel));
```